# Missing end boundary in multipart body

Tags: php, google-drive-api, guzzle

I am trying to upload a file to Google Drive using PHP. I am using the multipart type of uploading as it is a large file (MySQL database backup). This is to be run from a shell script for backup purposes.

Whenever posting a small file, my code works perfectly and the file is uploaded to Google Drive. However whenever I try to upload a larger file I get an error

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 39
Date: Mon, 06 Oct 2014 12:41:30 GMT
Server: UploadServer ("Built on Sep 24 2014 16:50:43 (1411602643)")
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=0.01

Missing end boundary in multipart body
```

A condensed output of what I am posting is

```
--54328df935387
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{"title":"MySQL backup","description":"Backup taken of MySQL database"}

--54328df935387
Content-Type: text/plain

-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.38, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
**ACTUAL DATA OMITTED**
-- Dump completed on 2014-10-06 23:41:29


--54328df935387--
```

The relevant PHP code is

```
$post = $client->createRequest('POST','https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart',['expect'=>false,'body'=>$string]);
$post->setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '.$access_token);
$post->setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/related; boundary="'.$boundary.'"');
$length = strlen(json_encode($metadata))+filesize('mysql_backup.sql');
$post->setHeader('Content-Length',$length);
try {
    $response = $client->send($post);
    echo $response->getBody();
} catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e){
    echo $e->getResponse();
}
```

I can only reproduce this error when posting larger than 1MB files.

I am using Guzzle to make the POST request. The boundary is generated by `uniqid()`.

Comment: Perhaps there is some sort of data limit on the Guzzle library that is causing the request to be truncated?

Comment: Can't you just let Guzzle handle the multipart-encoding and stuff ? Something like `$client->post('http://api/endpoint')->addPostFile('file', './mysql_backup.sql')->send();` ?

Comment: Guzzle works when adding a single file. However the Drive API requires making a multipart request - one with metadata and one with the actual file. Guzzle doesn't support this hence I have to build the request manually

Comment: It doesn't answer the question but I ended up using the Google PHP Client Library which works fine